# Unable to extract data from a Twitter Dataset

Tags: python, json, twitter

Trying to extract Extended_Tweet from within a JSON. This is the code I am using. It keeps giving me errors. How do I make it better?

```
def process(inputfn, outputfn):
report = []
for line in open(inputfn):
    ob = json.loads(line)
    try:
        data = tweet['extended_tweet']['full_text'] "").replace("\n", " ").replace("  ", " ").strip()
    except KeyError as e:
        print(e)
        data = tweet['stuff']
    user = ob.get("user")
    username = "unknown"

    if user:
        username = user.get("screen_name", "")
    msg = u"%s: %s" % (username, text)
    report.append(msg)

with codecs.open(outputfn, "w", "utf8") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(report))

if __name__ == "__main__":
process("data/test.json", "data/stream_test-part-tweets.txt")
```

Edit: Link to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/KTHwD5E5
 New Edit: Added updated code: Link: https://pastebin.com/Uf0Nb3bg

Comment: "It keeps giving me errors" => which ones ? That's the important part

Comment: @etene Yeah and please provide a JSON example (i.e. just print the json and post it here)

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You should use "tweet_mode=extended" on your API calls to retrieve extended Tweet objects. Then, you get the tweet text from tweet['extended_tweet']['full_text'], and if this value doesn't exists try : tweet['full_text'], then if no exists try : tweet['text']